# Can we have a user with the same powers/priviliges as root?

Tags: linux, unix, security, permissions, root

I am confused on the following in linux.
Can I have a user to have the same permissions as the root. In `Windows` any user can be the administrator but I am not clear exactly about this on `Linux`.
It seems that `root` is the "magic" account with all permissions, but can I create a user that has exactly the same permissions?
E.g. if I am user `jim` in `Linux` can `jim` be root? I am not talking about `sudo` but being able to do anything the root does.

Comment: It's no problem to have different usernames with uid 0 in the system. Use `useradd -o -u 0 rootz ...` e.g.. I've used that to have a root login with a different shell.

Comment: @ott:Could upgrade `jim` to be root?

Comment: The preferred way is `sudo`, so `jim` could execute specific or all commands as root.

Comment: For the record, the Windows equivalent of the *nix `root` is actually `SYSTEM`.

Comment: @Jim You need to add more info in your post, what version of Linux are you running? Redhat, Ubuntu, etc.....

Comment: just set user id 0 for your user: http://pthree.org/2008/07/17/duplicate-uids-on-linux/

Comment: @ayvango That is a *horribly* bad and dangerous way to do it and should not be recommended to *anyone*. If you don't know what you're doing it's a very easy way to completely hose your system, and if you do know what you're doing you shouldn't need to be told.

Answer (score 6):

Is possible but not recommended  create an account with the same privileges as root, by several factors.

Check [Man adduser](http://linux.die.net/man/8/adduser).

Comment: Why did you remove the example? Your post would be much better if it included not only a link to the manpage, but a practical example of how to achieve what the OP needs.

Answer (score 2):

The preferred way to run commands with administrative privileges is `sudo` for CLI and `gksu` for GUI. Read up on `visudo` for info on how to configure access for users through these commands. If you're the only user on your system and not concerned about someone else using it and messing something up, it's possible to be able to execute commands as root without password for `sudo`.
You shouldn't run some applications as root, for example IRC. That's why there's sudo, and without it, commands are run as the current user by default to prevent unauthorized root access from application level.

Comment: `it's possible to be able to execute commands as root without password for sudo` How?

Comment: Check the `sudo` documentation on how to add `NOPASSWD` to your sudo user. **NOTE** this is not recommended because it makes it that much easier to make a horrible mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no, at least "no" means you won't have it behave like I think you expect.

In UNIX, there's UID 0, b.k.a root, and everyone else. This is coded in the kernel, it's not something you can easily change.

Yes, you could have `jim` also be UID 0, but then that mixes things up. Remember that you don't store user names really anyplace, you store userids, and reverse map it through /etc/passwd (or other maps like LDAP) when needed. So, when jim does `ls -l` in his dir, he'll probably see his files owned by root. `jim` isn't another account, as much as an alias for root. This aliasing doesn't seem to be what you want.

This aliasing can be useful. FreeBSD has root with shell /bin/sh (which sucks for interactive use, but is statically linked and doesn't use /usr) and toor, also UID 0, using /bin/tcsh. If the system went to hell, you used root, which depended on fewer things. But for routine maintenance, you'd use toor, which had an easier to use shell. But this is an alias, not two separate accounts, and not what you want.